# Command to check version

Tags: command-line, package-management

I am new to this platform so can some one help me out for some commands.

I need some commands on patching a server for only specific packages.

After upgrading packages how to figure out package updated to latest version or not ??

Answer (score 20):

There are a lot of different solutions/workarounds I'm going to mention some:

### 1. Find installed version

#### 1.1. dpkg

Use `dpkg -l pkg-name` to get package version, e.g:

```
$ dpkg -l firefox
```

it's going to give you some information:

```
||/ Name         Version                  Architecture    Description
+++-==========================================================================
ii  firefox      53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.  amd64           Safe and easy web brow
```

#### 1.2. pkg --version

Depends on your package switches like `-v` or `--version` might be available to you:

```
firefox -v
```

### 2. Last available version

#### 2.1. apt show

Then use `sudo apt update` to make sure your sources are up to date, and use `apt show firefox | grep -i version` to see the last version available.

#### 2.2. Ubuntu packages database

You can also check https://packages.ubuntu.com to search for your package version.

#### 2.3. apt changelog

As an alternative you can use `apt changelog pkg-name`, e.g `apt changelog firefox` this will connect to internet to get the last "change log" data so you don't have to update your sources for using this command.

#### 2.4. rmadison

The other option is `rmadison`, it remotely query the archive database about a packages, so you don't have to update your source in this option.

First install its package: `sudo apt install devscripts`, then use it like:

```
 rmadison -s zesty -a amd64  wget
```

it give you last available version of `wget` for "zesty" and "amd64" architecture.

Answer (score 4):

### Check if upgrades are available for a particular package

It is possible to use `apt-cache` like this,

```
$ apt-cache policy <package-name>  # generic

$ apt-cache policy firefox         # example with output
firefox:
  Installed: 53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

### Update source list

Update listing the sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or (newer syntax)

```
sudo apt update
```

### Upgrade a package

Upgrade a particular package (and whatever is needed to support the new version)

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

or (newer syntax)

```
sudp apt install <package-name>
```

### Upgrade all installed packages

Upgrade the installed packages, which have upgrades available

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

or (newer syntax)

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

### Man pages

See the manual pages

```
man apt-get
```

and

```
man apt
```

for more details.

Comment: HOW TO START AND STOP A SERVICE ??

Comment: Commands for rollback a package if something went wrong..

Comment: @Tyson, These are questions about different problems. Please ask separate questions about them! Short answer with example from the 'graphical desktop world': 1. `ctrl + alt + F1` to get a text screen; 2. `sudo service lightdm stop`; 3. do something while lightdm is stopped; 4. `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: Take care parsing the output of `apt-cache policy`. Some of the output text terms are localized.

Comment: Thanks for this comment @bleater :-) We can avoid localized output by prefixing like the following: `LANG=C apt-cache policy package-name`. In Ubuntu 22.04.x LTS firefox is packed via snap, which can be checked via `LANG=C snap list firefox`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to patch a server for only a particular package you can do `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>`. This will **upgrade** only that single package, and **only** if it is installed. You can then use `<packagename> --version` to verify the current version of the installed package. You can also use `dpkg -l | awk '$2=="<packagename>" { print $3 }'` to verify the version as well.